# Create relationships when scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

Hi I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to create a small blog site. I have two tables Posts and Comments. Each Post will have many comments. I generate the tables using these commands.

```
rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text author:string
rails g scaffold Comment body:string author:string
```

Now I want to add the relationship to the model classes. I add `has_many :comments` to the Post class and `belongs_to :post` to the Comment class. However when I try to call `post.comments` I get a runtime error saying `SQLException: no such column: comments.post_id`. Should I create a migration and add post_id under Comment or is there a way to achieve this when scaffolding?

Comment: See https://coderwall.com/p/f5mdoq for help.

Comment: Could you change the accepted answer for this question as the currently accepted answer is out of date? Thx

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Scaffold actually provides a way to generate relationships, you should use the `:references` data type

```
rails g scaffold Comment body:string author:string post:references
```

This will generate a migration for the comments table with a post_id field and index for it. The generator will also add `belongs_to :post` to the Comment model.

It will not however generate the reverse side of the relationship so you'll need to add

```
has_many :comments
```

to the Post model yourself. You will also need to add nested resource routing if this is something you need as the generator can not handle this.

Comment: When you manually add the has_many field how do you generate the migration?

Comment: @lapinkoira In the above example, the `post:references` bit that's included when scaffolding the Comments model will add a foreign key on a Comment referencing the Post that it belongs to. The `has_many :comments` relationship needs to be added to the Post model but doesn't require an additional migration.

Answer (score 9):

You are definitely on the right track. If you add the `post_id` column when generating the `Comment` scaffold your relationship will then work (although you still need to add the `has_many :comments` and `belongs_to :post`)

So the updated generator call would look like this:

```
rails g scaffold Comment body:string author:string post_id:integer
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use :foreign_key in this case as opposed to an :integer?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `belongs_to` like this:

```
rails g scaffold Comment body:string author:string post:belongs_to
```